# how can i use broadcast receiver in my application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, receiver

im trying use broadcast receivers. my manifest and BR class es here. When I press text I expect it to say "receiver worked". but it is not working. it just says "button pressed".
and stackoverflow expects me to write something

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mybroadcastreceiver">

    <application
        .
        .
        .
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MyFirstReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MyReceiver"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
class MyFirstReceiver : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        println("Receiver çalıştı")
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    fun myFunc(view : View){
        sendBroadcast(Intent("MyReceiver"))
        println("Butona basıldı")
    }
}
```

Comment: is `myFunc()` being called?

Comment: when i press textview, yes

Comment: Static broadcasts (Registered through) manifest, do not work after API level 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts):

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the
> manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts
> that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit
> broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you
> can use scheduled jobs instead.

You are using an **implicit** broadcast here. You need to make your broadcast **explicit**, which you can do either by specifying your package name or the exact component in the broadcast `Intent`, like this:

```
sendBroadcast(Intent(this, MyReceiver::class.java))
```

or

```
val intent = Intent("MyReceiver").apply {
    setPackage("com.example.mybroadcastreceiver")
}
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Comment: when i change my defaultconfig:targetsdk:26 to 25, thats work. thanks a lot

Comment: @burhan-taskesen that's not what you were supposed to get from this answer. Lowering target SDK to enable legacy behaviors is always just a crude workaround - it might be enough for in-house projects where you can test every device that runs it but most if not all app stores will just deny your app from being published unless you target one of the latest ones (for play store that's sdk 31).